# How can I start webfsd every time I boot up/log in?

Tags: startup

I am using [webfsd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man1/webfsd.1.html), a lightweight HTTP daemon, to serve static content to `http://localhost:80` as follows:

```
sudo webfsd -R ~/Documents/www/ -p 80 -f index.html
```

But I have to run this from the command line every time. I assume I can't add `sudo` commands to Startup Programs. So, how can I make it run without having to invoke it every time?

(I would *prefer* it to start at boot up, and be accessible without me having to log in, even if this means I need to move the location of the files. But starting when I log in is an acceptable second place prize. If it makes a difference, I would like to experiment later with HTTPS.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first idea was a simple upstart script. `/etc/init/webfs.conf`:

```
description "WebFS server"
start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up)
respawn
exec webfsd -F -p 80 -u d3vid -g d3vid /home/d3vid/Documents/www/ -f index.html
```

The `-u` and `-g` arguments are *really* important. These drop root privileges after binding the port... Which means there's not a net-accessible process running as root that can be exploited.

The other idea is running it on a high port (>1024) as you, auto-starting that however you like... And then either using a *real* server to reverse proxy (nginx is a common and lightweight tool here) from port 80... Or just use an iptables redirect.

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 10010 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 10010
```

The advantage there is webfs is *never* running as root... But then you're just left with needing to run the `iptable` commands as root every boot. Swings and roundabouts.

I think on balance, if you're not exposing the server to the internet directly, the first route is probably safe enough.

### But if you're going any further, dump WebFS and just use `nginx`...

- It does everything WebFS does (and a whole lot more)
- It's simple to use
- It's efficient beyond reason
- Its SSL has decent documentation
- Most importantly, lots of people have a vested interest in nginx remaining secure, including Canonical, so you'll get updates for it fast (critical when dealing with web-facing things)

To give you some sort of idea what efficient means, I have a webserver hosting around 20 domains, a few of them do some pretty serious traffic. nginx's four worker processes account for 15MB of RAM combined and no observable CPU time. It's insane.

Comment: it's my laptop serving only static files to me and anyone on my network, so not currently intended for internet access - but you can never be too paranoid, so thanks for the tip!